# My HTML Buttons aren't working

Tags: html, css, button

I have a Web page here that i am developing to further my knowledge in html/css/javascript and my buttons in my header don't seem to be working, the button:hover doesn't trigger at all and they don't redirect you to where there supposed to. Heres the code which I hop isn't to long and hard, but i put them in a comment tag which i hope will make it easier i have made it as easy as i can.
They are near the middle. Any help will be appreciated:

```
<html>
    <head><style>
    html, body {
    height:100%;
}
body {
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
header{
    width: 98.907%;
    background: #000097;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 62px !important;
    opacity:.8;
    border-style: Outset;
    border-color: blue;
}

.content {
    position:relative;
    height: 100%;
    width:600px; /* Sizing - any length */
    padding:60px 0 30px 0; /* Header height and footer height */
    margin:0 auto 0 auto; /* Center content */
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.sidebar1, .sidebar2 {
    background: #000047;
    top: -80px;
    bottom:-80px;
    width: 10px;
    position:absolute;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.search{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #141414;
    height: 28px;
    width: 180px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fbff00;
    border: 2px solid #fbff00;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding: 2px 4px 0px 4px;
    margin: 0;
}


.sidebar1 {

  left: -342px;

}

.sidebar2 {
  right: -239px;
}

#scrollable2 {
  background:green;
  height: 99%;
  min-width: 1273px;
  margin-left: -332px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  top: 60px;
    overflow:auto;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.button {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #f29c93;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #f29c93;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #f29c93;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #fe1a00), color-stop(1, #ce0100) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #fe1a00 5%, #ce0100 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fe1a00', endColorstr='#ce0100');
    background-color:#fe1a00;
    width: 1272px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #d83526;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #b23e35;
}.button:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ce0100), color-stop(1, #fe1a00) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ce0100 5%, #fe1a00 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ce0100', endColorstr='#fe1a00');
    background-color:#ce0100;
}.button:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

.button1 {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #caefab;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #caefab;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #caefab;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #77d42a), color-stop(1, #5cb811) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #77d42a 5%, #5cb811 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#77d42a', endColorstr='#5cb811');
    background-color:#77d42a;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #268a16;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    color:#306108;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #aade7c;
}.button1:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #5cb811), color-stop(1, #77d42a) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #5cb811 5%, #77d42a 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#5cb811', endColorstr='#77d42a');
    background-color:#5cb811;
}.button1:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
    background: #000047;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 30px;
}
.p {
    text-align: center;
    color: #bcbcbc;
    font-size: x-large;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
    </style>
    <script>

    </script>
    <title>Davids LAN Website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <table width="100%">
            <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <!-----
                    The Problem is here or mabye in the styling but for some reason my skin viewer page and chat page don't work, the hover style and the link opening





                    <td><a href="plugins.html"><button class="button1">Plugins</button></a></td>
                    <td><a href="upload.php"><button class="button1">Upload</button></a></td>
                    <td><p class="p">Davids LAN Site</p></td>
                    <td><a href="skinviewer.html"><button class="button1">Skin Viewer</button></a></td>
                    <td><a href="chat.php"><button class="button1">Chat</button></a></td>




                    ----->
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                </table>
        </header>
        <!-- Fixed size after header-->
        <div class="content">
        <div class="sidebar1">

        </div>
            <!-- Always on top. Fixed position, fixed width, relative to content width-->
            <!-- Scrollable div with main content -->
            <div id="scrollable2">
            <a href="http://dl.bukkit.org/downloads/craftbukkit/get/01479_1.3.2-R3.0/craftbukkit.jar" target="_blank">
                <button class="button"><img src="https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/profile_images/1205959797/bukkit_normal.png"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Download Craftbukkit</button></a>
            <p class="p">How to set up Bukkit Server</p>
            <center><video width="800" controls="controls">
                <source src="movies/bukkit.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="movies/bukkit.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
                </video><video width="800" controls="controls">
                <source src="movies/regular.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="movies/regular.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
                </video></center>
                &nbsp;
                <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJD6E8J5Ioc&feature=plcp" target="_blank">
                <button class="button">If you have Firefox please click here to view the youtube videos
                </button>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Always on top. Fixed position, fixed width, relative to content width -->
        </div>
        <!-- Always at the end of the page -->
        <footer>

        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please reduce your example code to the necessary parts.

Comment: Could you put your code on jsfiddle.net ? This will make it easier for everyone to test out their possible solutions. And also what Sirko said, try to keep it simple.

Comment: you might want to check a tutorial.  for starters, hover is not a valid action for a button.  only for `a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.location='plugins.html';" value="Plugins">
```